# Assignment of variable is not getting picked up in makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, variable-assignment

I am using a makefile where there is a line like

```
VAR=$(MVAR) command1;
```

Now when command1 executes i want VAR to retain the value what is being assigned by MVAR which is required for the successful completion of command1.
But unfortunately VAR contains some default value while executing command1, ie VAR is not able to hold the value assigned during assignment while executing command1.

if same command i run in any of the shell the value of VAR is retained and command1 gets executed successfully.

Nearly tried everything to run it on makefile.
Can somebody please explain me the reason behind this behavior in gnu makefile and possible solution. I am using Linux as OS and ksh as shell for Makefile.

Comment: What you're doing should work (set VAR in the environment to the value of the make variable MVAR), so something else is going on.  More context, maybe?

Comment: Hi rra...
MVAR here keeps changing during execution of makefile. So can't set it up in env.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear: the line `VAR=$(MVAR) command` in a make rule runs that command in the shell with the value of the make variable MVAR substituted in.  This in turn sets VAR in the environment to the value of MVAR before running `command`.  In other words, what you're doing should work, assuming that description is what you expect to have happen.  If `command` is not seeing VAR set in the environment, something weird is going on, possibly in other parts of the makefile that aren't shown in the question.

Comment: Can you try doing this `echo VAR=$(MVAR); VAR=$(MVAR) command1` - to debug if `VAR` is indeed getting the right value of `MVAR` you expect it to ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a command in a rule, just add (or move) a semicolon:

```
VAR=$(MVAR); command1
```

But I suspect there may be more involved. If this doesn't work, please give us more context (e.g. the makefile and some information about `command1`).

Comment: Hi Beta,

Thnx for answering.

Yes this command is a part of rule in the make file.
I already tried ; and export, it does not work.
To be more precise i am running a command(gencat) which is locale specific and every time i need VAR to pass different locale to command gencat to process message files written in that locale.

Answer (score 0):

what sort of thing are you expecting `MYVAR` to be set to?  If it contains spaces or other characters meaningful to the shell, what you are doing won't work.  You could try quoting it:

```
        VAR='$(MVAR)' command1
```

and see if that works better.

Also, this depends on your shell being a standard POSIX bourne-shell derivative (sh, bash, ksh, zsh all qualify; the Windows cmd processor does not).

Comment: Hi Chris,
Already tried this...
It does not work.
Beside that, My makefile uses ksh as shell.
i am running a command(gencat) which is locale specific and every time i need VAR to pass different locale to command gencat to process message files written in that locale.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried VAR:=$(MYVAR)? (i.e. `:=` instead of `=`)

This forces VAR to be assigned the value immediately, rather than being lazily evaluated.